# How do I start Unity manually upon boot?

Tags: boot, unity, gui

I recently installed [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr) LTS, and I was wondering how could I start the GUI manually upon booting the system.

For example, I'd like the system to start at a black `tty` screen, ask for my credentials and password, and then I can start the GUI manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run the following command in terminal:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

This opens the [GRUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB) boot loader configuration file with a text editor.

2. Do the below changes:

Comment the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`, by adding # at the beginning, which will disable the Ubuntu purple screen.

Change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="text"`. This makes Ubuntu boot directly into text mode.

Uncomment this line `#GRUB_TERMINAL=console`, by removing the # at the beginning. This makes GRUB menu into real black & white text mode (without a background image).

After saving the changes, update GRUB via the command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Restart your computer and see the result.

To get the GUI, run `sudo lightdm`.

[Reference](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/01/boot-into-text-console-ubuntu-linux-14-04/)

Comment: thanks i did what you posted and it disabled the automatic installation of the gui. but i have 2 little problems:
1- i receive "sda1 write same failed. manually zeroing" next to the login prompt (no problems on entering credentials/password though)
2- when I enter "startx" nothing initializes but the desktop. No sidebar or the bar at the top for system settings etc. I'd appreciate your help if you could help me.

Comment: I don't know about the first one, but I would suggest trying the command `sudo lightdm` for the second one, not startx?

Answer (score -1):

You need to boot in run level 3 (where you get only the command line) and then you can type `init 5` (witch will go in run level 5 with GUI)

Comment: The concept of Runlevels is not applicable on Ubuntu any more.